# When to use '$(this)' and 'this' in a jQuery plugin? (Article on net.tutsplus.com)

Tags: jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins, coding-style

I'm learning jQuery now, and was reading an article of Jeffrey Way, ["You Still Can’t Create a jQuery Plugin?"](http://net.tutsplus.com/videos/screencasts/you-still-cant-create-a-jquery-plugin/) 
Almost everything is clear, but there are some points that I still cannot understand.

Problems begin on the 'Step 3: Building the Plugin', heading title 'For Each...', and next 'Error Checking'.

```
   this.each(function() {  
     $this = $(this);
     var title = this.title; 
     if ($this.is('a') && $this.attr('title') != '') {  
       this.title = '';  
       $this.hover(function(e){
```

Questions

1. `this.title` - what a method is it? When we use jQuery we type `$(this).attr('title')` - and jQuery was created to simplify development) 
   Does `this.title` refer to a DOM Specification, or Javascript built-in methods?
2. I totally cannot understand what is going on with `this` keyword here, when do we have to use `this` and when `$(this)`? Why do we use `this.each(func`..., and not `$(this).each(func`...? (I've tested it - and it works too, but what is a difference?) I know that factory method `$()` returns a wrapped set of DOM elements, but why do we use `this.title` here (and again `$(this).attr('title')` does the job)? 
   I made a little bit of testing. We can type `this.title` or `title` instead of `$this.attr('title')` in the conditional statement, but if only we use anything (`title` or `$(this).attr('title')`) instead of `this.title` in the statement `this.title = '';` - it doesn't work.
3. Well, we specified `var title = this.title;`. But when we use this variable, why do we declare it?

I think that some of you can understand even better than me, understanding of what things I need, so I finish my explanation)
Thank you very, very much, if you can make it clear)

Answer (score 1):

1. Using jQuery's `attr('title', newVal)` method you would be able to apply a single value to all elements included in your jQuery selector, but to change a single element it is simpler to just manipulate the element's `title` attribute directly
2. In the `each()` function, the `this` parameter is the item being iterated over. When iterating over a collection of DOM elements, `this` will be a DOM element. If you want to use jQuery functions on DOM elements you need to wrap them in jQuery again, meaning you need to use `$(this).doAwesomeness()`
3. The `var title` is probably being used within the function nested inside `$this.hover()`

Comment: Sorry, but you might be mistaking, there is no title() method as I know. You mean, $(grabAwesomeness).attr('title', setValue).
Can you tell, please, what attributes can we manipulate directly, any attribute? Do I have to reread "DOM Scripting"? ))

Comment: Sorry, I wrote that before I had my coffee this morning. I meant to say `.attr('title')`. And yes, that can manipulate or retrieve any attribute from a jQuery'd DOM element or collection of DOM elements.

Comment: I want to write some comments about what you said in paragraph №1:
by using this keyword we are also able to manipulate all elements in a wrapped set. But if we want (as you said in paragraph №2) to use jQuery functions on a wrapped set, we should use $(this).
Am I right in that points?

Comment: But we still can use this.each(function() {}), but .each(function() {}) is jQuery's function. No, something is still unclear for me.

Answer (score 0):

As you said yourself the $() function returns a wrapped set of DOM elements which adds the jquery functionality to it. The reason $(this).attr('title') won't exchange for this.title is because the correct way to use that function is like this

```
$(this).attr( 'title', '' );
```

and not

```
$(this).attr( 'title' ) = '';
```

you can't use title = '' either because title is a local variable not a reference to the attribute itself.

Comment: Thank you)
And can you explain a little bit, please: 'title is a local variable not a reference to the attribute itself'
But I can type if (... && title != '') {
And the code will work correctly.
So, what does it mean?

Comment: When you go "var title = this.title;" you are creating a local variable with the value of this.title at that point in time. If you change this.title it will not change title and if you change title it will not change this.title. Title simply holds the same value as this.title because you told it to.

Answer (score 0):

1. this.title is the object's title attribute in plain JS DOM. (http://w3schools.com/htmldom/prop_title.asp).

The following is equivalent with jQuery and normal JS:

```
 var  blah = this.title;  // is the same as...
 var  blah = $(this).attr('title');

 this.title = 'blah';     // is the same as ...
 $(this).attr('title', 'blah');
```

2. this is a pointer to the object that fired an event or a method you are running belongs to, all methods in JavaScript belong to a parent object of some kind.
3. $(object) will attach the jQuery wrappers to a standard object (giving you access to use all the jQuery methods/etc on that object)